# How to $\int e^{-u^2/2} du$

Tags: integration

How to $$\int e^{-u^2/2} du$$

I tried substitutions $y=-u^2$ and $y=\frac{-u^2}{2}$ but I dont think I am getting it right.

Comment: You can't express the result of integration in [elementary functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

Comment: On the other hand, people often want to calculate it, especially in statistics.  It is related to the *error function* which is written $erf(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you may  use the trick of double integral: $$\int_R e^{-x^2/2} dx \int_R e^{-y^2/2} dy= \int_{R^2} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} dxdy$$ then use polar coordinates to change the variables, $$\int_{R^2} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} dxdy=\int_{R^2} e^{-(r^2)/2} rdrd\theta=2\pi\int_{R^+} e^{\frac{r^2}{2}} d\frac{r^2}{2}=2\pi$$
so $$\int_R e^{-x^2/2} dx =\sqrt{2\pi}$$
However I do not know how to calculate the indifinite integral.

Comment: You're going to want to throw bounds of integration on your integral. Also, that function does not have an elementary anti-derivative.

Comment: You are right, I just recalled that fact, are there some references on that (and on how to tell if an function has elementary anti-derivative or not)?